# MySQL left outer join multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, inner-join, where-clause

Table: **Bookmark**

```
  bid      bname    tagid1      tagid2      tagid3
--------------------------------------------------------------------
   1      bookmark1  1001        1002        1003
   2      bookmark2  1002                    1005
   3      bookmark3              1003        1003
   4      bookmark4                          1003
   5      bookmark5  1001                
   6      bookmark5  1002                    1003
```

Table: **Tag**

```
  tagid       tagname  
--------------------------
   1001        Java  
   1002        PHP
   1003        Ruby  
   1004        Node.js
   1005        Go
```

The result I expect to get is :

```
  bid      bname    tagName1    tagName2    tagName3
--------------------------------------------------------------------
   1      bookmark1  Java        PHP         Ruby
   2      bookmark2  PHP                     Go
   3      bookmark3              Ruby        Ruby
   4      bookmark4                          Ruby
   5      bookmark5  Java                
   6      bookmark5  PHP                     Ruby
```

How could I get this?

Comment: are your tags fixed numbers ? or flexible

Comment: Join the tag table once for each tag in the bookmark table.

Comment: @POHH auto_increment

Comment: This is called PIVOT Table or Transpose Rows into columns see a solution here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47902/how-to-transpose-convert-rows-as-columns-in-mysql

Comment: Should questions about SQL posted on stackoverflow or http://dba.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos No, This is a different thing. To solve this only multiple joins are required, no pivoting.

Comment: @Sam SO should be fine, DBA overlaps but maybe tends to be more about admin of specific dbms I think.

Comment: @jpw Yeah, you are rigth, didn't pay attention to the bookmark table. Thanks though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to join the same table multiple times. You need a table name alias for each one to distinguish them

```
select b.id, b.bname,
       t1.name as tagName1,
       t2.name as tagName2,
       t3.name as tagName3
from bookmark b
left join tag t1 on t1.tagid = b.tagid1
left join tag t2 on t2.tagid = b.tagid2
left join tag t3 on t3.tagid = b.tagid3
```

BTW you should consider changing your table design by adding another table for the mapping of bookmark-tags. Then you can have any number of tags for each bookmark.

Comment: I think that it worth to say that this is for fixed number of tags.

Comment: The current table design has exactly 3 possible tags

Comment: Yeah, you are right, didn't pay attention to the bookmark table. +1